# How to find mismatch data between two tables based of certain columns

Tags: loops, join, database-reconciliation

Note : We have millions of records so searching for optimal solution.
Task 1) I have two tables Table_A and Table_B which is having columns like Projectid, studyid, panelid, udf1, udf2, udf3 and I want to perform reconciliation on it based on columns UDf1, UDf2, Udf3 etc. I am able to achieve the matched data between two tables simply doing the inner join on columns a.udf1=b.udf1 and a.udf2=b.udf2 and a.udf3=b.udf3. now I want to find out mismatch rows based on these udf columns in both tables. Even if one column of UDF value is mismatched either for Table_a or Table_b it should be consider as
mismatch row.

Task 2) Now I have another table called Table_panel. now I want to update this Panel table based on panel Id's which have completed their reconciliation. lets say Panelid=1 has completed its reconciliation which is nothing but the task 1) logic the it should marked as 'Completed ' in table_panel. and this should happen in loop until it covers all panelid's.

Can somebody please help me with solution in Oracle.

Want to find out mismatch data between two tables. Basically want to perform reconciliation